# how to parse an xml response with multiple name tags in it

Tags: android

Hi i am usin XML PULL PARSER for parsing my response as the response it too large about 6mb of size. The response contains multiple name tags in it. How can i parse to attain string tags seperately for respective name tags . My response is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
- <methodResponse>
- <params>
- <param>
- <value>
- <array>
- <data>
- <value>
  <int>7</int> 
  </value>
- <value>
- <struct>
- <member>
  <name>AdURLs</name> 
- <value>
- <struct>
- <member>
  <name>small</name> 
- <value>
- <array>
- <data>
- <value>
  <string>http://www.jumptap.com/images/cg-windowshade-collapsed.jpg</string> 
  </value>
- <value>
  <string>http://mobilesitelinkexchange.com/images/stories/320x50mobile_standard.gif</string> 
  </value>
  </data>
  </array>
  </value>
  </member>
- <member>
  <name>large</name> 
- <value>
- <array>
- <data>
- <value>
  <string>http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_5pkoVwxuN90/S-RpGWWgshI/AAAAAAAACoU/HlB9I5WOo4g/s400/iphone_jd1003.jpg</string> 
  </value>
- <value>
  <string>http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_5pkoVwxuN90/S_vW6bHZgMI/AAAAAAAACqs/CpQ05gcYtTA/s320/iphone-ps5032.jpg</string> 
  </value>
  </data>
  </array>
  </value>
  </member>
- <member>
  <name>medium</name> 
- <value>
- <array>
- <data>
- <value>
  <string>http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/be/Ads-300x250.gif</string> 
  </value>
- <value>
  <string>http://www.wrestling-online.com/images/ads/300x250/nomercy2008.jpg</string> 
  </value>
  </data>
  </array>
  </value>
  </member>
  </struct>
  </value>
  </member>
```

Comment: Ouch, did you just copy the XML from Internet Explorer? Bad idea. Open the XML file as text, copy it, paste it in the editor and press the `{}` button to format it as code and preserve the tags.

Comment: i want to take string value whose name value is small, in one arraylist. And respectively for string values medium and large. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I'm rather big fan of pull parser, this time I would recommend using SAX parser instead. It causes some overhead compared to pull parser but your DefaultHandler implementation could be rather simple as it's possible to listen to only very few elements you're interested in, and their contents.

With pull parser the problem is not so much to find start tags - but finding related end tag - while you should search for child tags/contents at the same time. I'm guessing all this would end up into such recursion, rather hard to handle and error prone if xml has some unexpected content, you find stack based parsing in SAX more comfortable quite quickly.

Also if your xml size is counted in megabytes, and you have possibility to have changes made on server, you might find using GZIPped stream more comfortable. If data comes over socket/http/etc that is.

Comment: thnx...i knw it can be done with SAX Parser.../.Bt is it possible in anyway that the same result can be achieved using Pull Parser

Comment: Quite obviously it's possible but it would be much more easier if your xml didn't contain e.g. embedded <member> elements but they were named differently for each level, maybe describing content in a bit more detail. That way skipping uninteresting content would be a bit more clear as you could do it until certain end element and didn't have to worry about parsing level/depth at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use xPath:

http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html